# Validate l() before moving to different location

Tags: drupal-7, hyperlink, block, form-api

This would be most simple functional question in Drupal 7.
Now below mentioned things are mandatory to do and cant change the functionality.
1) I have created a custom block in module.
2) I have included form like below:-

```
function usercontent_block_view($delta='') 
{

   $block = array();    
   switch($delta)
   {
     case 'user_front_page' :        
       $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('genre_all_login');                       
     break;
   }
   return $block; 
}
```

3) Now I have some other content in block but which put me in trouble is shown below:-

```
function genre_all_login($form) {
  $form['new_user'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#markup' => l('Add New User','http://www.google.com'),            
    );
    return $form; 
  }
```

4) So it includes a link which will move me to Google once clicked.
5) Now I want to validate certain content inside the block before user navigates to Google.So if the condition doesn't match then I will stop the user by showing an error message and hence user cannot traverse to Google.

Please tell me if it is possible or should I use different technique to handle this scenario.

Comment: do you need to _validate_ through PHP or the validation process can be done with JavaScript?

Comment: I need to validate using PHP

Comment: Do you want to validate after submitting the form or just while clicking on the generated link?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `#markup` like:

```
l('Add New User','http://www.google.com', array('attributes' => array('class' => 'validate_with_js') ))
```

And then you can write a JavaScript code to validate:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.validate_with_js').click(function() {
        // Your Validation Cdoe. You can use AJAX here if you need to validate through PHP.
    });
});
```

If you want to validate after submission of the form then you can use `#element_validate`.

Comment: I will try to achieve functionality using this. Thanks for response.